# how to make React i18next accessing json file in django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, localization, i18next

I'm using React build folder inside Django. When React i18next uploads locales/en/translation.json from the build folder in Django I get an error as wsgiserver uploads the file as text/html instead of json.

is there a way to call this file as json or make wsgiserver/django ignor upload it as json ?
can i add function to this line in i18n.js to make sure it's fetched as json : backend: {
loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
},

i18n.js ;

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide
// for passing in lng and translations on init

const Languages = ['ar', 'en', 'fr']

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    react: {
      useSuspense: true,
    },
    // the translations
    // (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
    // or even better, manage them via a UI: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files#manage-your-translations-with-a-management-gui)
    supported: ["en", "fr", "ar"],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
    },
    debug: true,
    whitelist: Languages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    nsSeperator: false,
    keySeperator: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

debug console :

```
i18next.js:27 i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace translation for language en failed failed parsing /locales/en/translation.json to json
```

network/headers ;

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/locales/ar/translation.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: same-origin
Content-Length: 948
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2022 19:43:46 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.2
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=KKBUsud0hxf0n2XkfSuQw9Hx3RLkHnSTyJHzGL8xyg502fPxxcDab3113rLJxQyu; i18next=ar
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

settings.py ;

```
from datetime import timedelta
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-uop@o(x&p6u4dc5+)#1bn&fh&03n*!i9+w80s38ci6q@-ju&cb'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'application_form.apps.ApplicationFormConfig',
    'social.apps.SocialConfig',
    'contacts.apps.ContactsConfig',
    'service_request.apps.ServiceRequestConfig',
    'partners.apps.PartnersConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'prosperity.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')], # add inside [] os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build') we'll get error when we run the server but it's temporery the build will come once we do our frontend
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'prosperity.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx?',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}

# email addition
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'hello@xxxx.co'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS='hello@xxxx.co'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'

TIME_ZONE = 'CET'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
'%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', 
'%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y',
'%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',  
'%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',  
'%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',  
'%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y', 
]

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ],
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS=0o640

# Token settings
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',
    )
}

#Red Djoser web Token settings
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD':'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/application-form/', include('application_form.urls')),
    path('api/service-request/', include('service_request.urls')),
    path('api/social/', include('social.urls')),
    path('api/contacts/', include('contacts.urls')),
    path('api/partners/', include('partners.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

#RED
urlpatterns +=[re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

Comment: When you access this JSON file using a browser, what is the result? It shows a JSON? Maybe your path is incorrect and you are loading a html (event the url ending with translation.json). The url do not start with /static/ for example, that make me thing that django is trying to answer a page not linking to a static asset.

Comment: Thanks brother. to solve the issue I placed the locales folder inside static and all works well. Django reads everything inside this folder as static

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue I placed the locales folder inside static and all works well. Django reads everything inside this folder as static